# How do I use html code in an .inc file which is called by a php file?

Tags: php, html, include

Title seems a little butchered, but basically I have a php file that is trying to call .inc file with includes code for a menu. I'm using:

```php
<?php
    include_once("php_menu.inc")
?>
```

And this is my HTML code:

```html
<nav>
        <ul>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="topic.html">Information</a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

But how do I write this in php_menu.inc so that it's actually picked up?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include what the actual issue is? What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Did you actually get as far as trying something? Like sticking the HTML inside the php_menu.inc (not in PHP Tags) OR Assigning it as string and then echoing it where you want it from the main file... OR....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.

Imagine this is your folder structure and your file names:

```
/inc
  /menu
     php_menu.inc
  /nav
     nav.inc
index.php
```

Your page which calls the files (index.php for example)

```
<?php
    include_once("inc/menu/php_menu.inc");
?>
```

php_menu.inc

```
<?php
include('inc/nav/nav.inc');
?>
```

nav.inc

```
<nav>
        <ul>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="topic.html">Information</a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```